# Google Sheets/Excel: Checking if a time falls within a range

Tags: time, google-sheets

I'm trying to find a way to see if I can find a way to determine if a time that I stipulate falls between two other times. For example:

```
Start       End
11:33:48    11:53:48
12:20:22    12:38:21
12:39:27    13:00:09
14:16:23    14:20:49
14:20:54    14:22:56
```

Then, I want to check if a cell (here the value of 12:50 in cell E30) falls between ANY two values in a range in THE SAME ROW.  For me, I can get the obvious way to check for this in one row, and this simple version totally works:

```
=If(AND(E30>A4,E30<B4), "TRUE", "FALSE")
```

However, I want to check if that number falls within ANY of the values within the ROWS above cells in a range, and I can't get that to work. For example, I tried this and it didn't work:

```
=If(AND(E30>A:A,E30<B:B), "TRUE", "FALSE")
```

I also tried a simple countif variation but that didn't do it either:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">"&E30,B:B,"<"&E30)
```

Any advice on how to adjust one of these formulas to get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for the above data set -

```
=IF((FILTER(A2:B6, D2>A2:A6,D2<B2:B6)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

This will give you if there is any match or not.

For the number of rows count that match -

```
=ROWS((FILTER(A2:B6, D2>A2:A6,D2<B2:B6)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try switching the angle brackets around:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<"&E30,B:B,">"&E30)
```

Answer (score -2):

Alomsot    =IF(Q2>R2,IF(AND($X$16>HOUR(Q2),$X$16<(HOUR(R2)+12)),1,0),IF(AND(HOUR($X$14)>=HOUR(Q2),HOUR($X$14)<=HOUR(R2)),1,0))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] the post accordingly. Specifically, always remember you are not just debugging a piece of code, you are giving a solution with information. So please explain **why** this code would solve the problem at hand.